# C++ uninitialized class arrays

Tags: c++, class, constructor

In my studies, I have learned that if you want to prevent users from calling the default constructor of a class, you can make it private:

```
class Person
{
public:
  Person(const Person&);
  ~Person();
private:
  Person();  //Any call to this will cause a compiler error.
};
```

What I don't understand is when I create an uninitialized array of the class, it gives me a syntax error saying that it is private:

```
Person * ptr;   //Works just fine.
Person arr[1];  //Syntax error: 'Person::Person()' is private
```

This would leave me to believe that it makes an attempt to call the default constructor when the array is created. But this doesn't make any sense to me since I'm not actually creating any real objects.

Comment: When you declare `Person arr[1]` you create array with one element and with default constructor called (which is private) and with `Person * ptr` you delcare just a pointer.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a `pointer` to a `Person` and an array which contains elements of the type `Person`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Person * ptr;   //Works just fine. 
Person arr[1];  //Syntax error: 'Person::Person()' is private
```

> This would leave me to believe that it makes an attempt to call the
>   default constructor when the array is created. But this doesn't make
>   any sense to me since I'm not actually creating any real objects.

Here is your mistake.  In your second example (the one that fails) you are creating a real object.   You are defining an array of Persons (people?!) with one element/object.

Therefore you are creating an object to go into that array.

Remember when an object gets created - what happens?
A constructor is called, if there is no suitable definied constructor what does the compiler 
do?

It uses the default one - but it cannot because it is private.

Answer (score 8):

You're not creating an uninitialized array. You're creating an array of `Person` objects. And they have to be initialized *somehow*. If no constructor exists, then it will fall back to the default initialization rules (which might leave some members with unspecified values). But when a constructor is declared, it has to be used.

There is no such thing as an "uninitialized" object in C++. An object exists when it has been constructed, and during construction, it is initialized, in *some* way, depending on what the object looks like.

Comment: "There is no such thing as an "uninitialized" object in C++" -- that's a relief, since the standard talks about them (for example in `[conv.lval]`), and they're bad news ;-) Of course what it means in your terms is an lvalue expression referring to a region of memory which is not (yet) an object. Your terms are more precise, they should get you to help draft the next one.

Comment: That's true. And yeah, this is a somewhat simplified version. I hope that it conveys the right idea, even if the wording is different from what the standard says.

Answer (score 1):

```
Person * ptr;
```

This does not create a Person object. it's just an pointer with uninitialized value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Person * ptr; is a pointer and it is not initialized
Person arr[1]; is an array of Person and for each element it is called Person()
as a default constructor
```

Because you overwrite Person() the compiler will take your Person() constructor and because it is private it will give you and error because you can't call a private method from outside the class

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between the 2 lines

```
Person * ptr;   //Works just fine.
Person arr[1];
```

In the first line, you have just declared a pointer, but not allocated memory. So the constructor is not yet called. Hence it does not give any error.

Try this if you want to be more clear

```
ptr = new Person();
```

In the second line, you are instantiating an array of the class objects, which will call the costructor. Hence you are getting the error